# Can I install Parallels 5.0 for Mac and then Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation

I have an older Mac OS X version 10.5.8 with 2.1 GHz PowerPC G5 and 1.5 GB DDR2 SDRAM memory.  I want to run Windows 7 on it.  I don't think I have Snow Leopard and I don't have Boot Camp.
1)  Can Boot Camp be installed?
2)  Then do I have enough RAM to install Windows 7 using Parallels 5.0 for Mac?
   I'm not very computer savvy with Apples.

Jerry

Answer (score 2):

You'll need an intel Mac to run windows 7 through boot camp or parallels. Virtual PC runs on PowerPC and may run win 7, but I think it would be horribly slow.

Answer (score 0):

In order to tell what type of OS X you have installed you can click the apple in the top left and select about this mac.

- 10.6 = snow leopard
- 10.5 = leopard
- 10.4 = jaguar..etc

I know that as far back as jaguar (10.4) offered the ability to do bootcamp but at the time it was a beta feature.

The main issue is your lack of ram.  If you used boot camp, you may be ok.  That would be your best bet.  The minimum amount of ram for Windows 7 is [1gb for 32 bit OS and 2GB for 64 bit](http://windows.microsoft.com/systemrequirements).

As far as Parallels 5.0, Win 7 is compatible but not going to happen.  I would suggest an upgrade in RAM and buying snow leopard if you don't have it.

Comment: Jerry says in the question what the OS version is. Also, extra RAM won't help as it doesn't have the correct processor. Finally, snow leopard is not PowerPC compatible.

Comment: @chris you're completely right I overlooked the powerpc.. good catch

Comment: My user guide info says Tiger 10.4 is what I have.  I guess I'm dumb 71 year-old but do I have a PowerPC and would more RAM and Snow Leopard help or not help?  Sorry to be so dense.

Comment: @Jerry - There's nothing dumb about asking questions; at any age. :)
You state in your question that you have a PowerPC G5 i.e. it has a PowerPC processor - if that is the case, RAM won't help as the processor is not supported. And for the same reason, Snow Leopard will not install. You would need to have a Mac with an Intel processor. Does that make help it make sense?

Comment: Thanks for the help.  All I want to do is run Windows 7 on my Mac.  If I use Parallels 5.0 can I install Win 7 and use it?  If not, what are my options?